# In the night I softly bellow

Tags: riddle

> Strong as the great ocean's billow
>   Yet softer than a feather pillow
>   In the night I softly bellow
>   As I caress the aging willow

Comment: I can see a picture from your riddle =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The wind

Reason:

> Strong as the oceans billows: strong winds. 
>  Softer than a feather pillow: gentle wind
>  Caressing the old willow: a gentle blowing wind

Answer (score 4):

It must be:

> air (or wind)

Strong as the great ocean's billow

> Windstorms are strong.

Yet softer than a feather pillow

> Air is soft, and generally feels smooth

In the night I softly bellow

> Wind makes sound when it flows

As I caress the aging willow

> Winds

Comment: Almost there, good job anyway! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Strong as the great ocean's billow

Yet softer than a feather pillow

In the night I softly bellow

As I caress the aging willow

I think it is

> cloud